# Select middle rows in Django ORM

Tags: mysql, django

In normal sql, to select exactly 'n' rows, starting from 'r'th row, we can do the following query:

```
select * from someTable where target_user_id = user_id limit r,n;
```

In Django, the closest I could get is:

```
someTable.objects.filter(target_user_id=user_id, id__gte=r).values_list('user_id',flat=True)[:n]
```

But this is not same as my raw sql query.
Can anyone please explain what the equivalent django query will be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
someTable.objects.all()[r:r+n]
```

This is just like normal lists:

```
In [10]: t = range(1,10)

In [11]: r = 2

In [12]: n = 3

In [13]: t[r:r+n]
Out[13]: [3, 4, 5]
```

Django will transform this into SQL query with limit.

Comment: Ah !! How did I miss this !!